# Can I use RM-ANOVA with unbalanced within-subject design with sphericity violated?

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, unbalanced-classes, sphericity

I have data from an EEG experiment. Originally, the design was balanced, but because in EEG you loose a lot of data to noise and malfunctioning equipment, the end-result is unbalanced data.

I am working with R. In R, my data looks like this:

```
          Name                 Condition Channel EpochCountStd EpochCountDeviant ErpMinTime ErpMinVoltage ErpMinAv Frequency
380   AY11042016B1-Deci.EEG      HFMM     AF3           423               103        203          -1.2     -1.1      High
388 AvdP23052016B1-Deci.EEG      HFMM     AF3           410               101        144          -3.7     -3.2      High
397   EW20042016B1-Deci.EEG      HFMM     AF3           457               118        123          -2.6     -2.3      High
413  IG160312016B1-Deci.EEG      HFMM     AF3           435               105        214          -2.2     -1.6      High
422  IJB18042016B1-Deci.EEG      HFMM     AF3           408               110        121          -1.3     -1.1      High
439   MC31032016B1-Deci.EEG      HFMM     AF3           438               101        116          -4.0     -3.3      High
        Hemisphere  Region      Lexicality Subject
380       Left AnterioFrontal       Word Subject08
388       Left AnterioFrontal       Word Subject14
397       Left AnterioFrontal       Word Subject12
413       Left AnterioFrontal       Word Subject02
422       Left AnterioFrontal       Word Subject10
439       Left AnterioFrontal       Word Subject05
```

For present purposes, my dependent variable is `ErpMinAv`, a continuus numerical variable and my independent variables are `Lexicality` (2 levels), `Frequency`(2 levels), `Hemisphere`(3 levels) and `Region` (5 levels).

Moreover, I have tested for sphericity and the result is highly significant, meaning my data violate the sphericity assumptions.

I have already run anovas and regressions on my data, but I am always onsure of some things:

1. Should I be using anova if I am violating the sphericity assumption? I understand most statistical programs include corrections in the tests themselves, but from what I have read on the internet, this is not necessarily the case in R. I have seen people recommending the use of `lm()` or `lme4()`.
2. How should I order my independent variables in the R syntax? So far, I tried:

   ```
   MM_Model <- aov(ErpMinAv ~ Lexicality*Frequency*Hemisphere*Region 
                   + Error(Subject),data = MM_Table)
   ```

But I have seen different ways of ordering the factors (e.g. with sums instead of multiplication signs) and many different ways of writing the `Error()` term (e.g. like this: `Error(Subject/(v1*v2*v3*v4`). I have not, however, been able to find explanations for a case where there is no sphericity and the data is unbalanced.